# How to avoid maven shade plugin from including transitive dependencies from 'test-jar' types?

Tags: maven, apache-spark, maven-shade-plugin

I am working on a multi-module Maven project which has intermodule dependencies. For example: One of the project's module, say `spark-module` has a dependency on another module (say `core-module`) from the same project.

The `core-module` has a dependency on `jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.8.11` and in the `spark-module`, I have added the test-jars from the Apache Spark project - `spark-sql_2.11:2.4.0`, `spark-core_2.11:2.4.0`, `spark-catalyst_2.11:2.4.0` for unit testing purpose. As you see, these Spark modules are all of version 2.4.0 which internally uses `jackson-databind:2.6.7.1`. Please refer the POM provided below:

**Parent**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-test</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>core-module</module>
        <module>spark-module</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

**core-module**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>spark-test</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>core-module</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>

</project>
```

**spark-module**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>spark-test</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>spark-module</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.holdenkarau</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-testing-base_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0_0.12.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-catalyst_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                    <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactSet>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>org.apache.spark:*</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </artifactSet>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Now when I build `spark-module`, when maven shade plugin kicks in, it includes the `jackson-databind:2.6.7.1` instead of 2.8.11 (I thought it would come from `core-module`). When I add the following exclusions to the `test-jar` dependencies, it properly bundles the 2.8.11 version JAR but that makes my tests fail since the dependencies are excluded:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the way the dependencies are handled. So can you please help me understand what should be done here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To control the version of `jackson-databind`, add an entry to the `<dependencyManagement>` section in which you specify the version you want. This will override all transitive definitions and is much easier to handle than various exclusions.

So in the first step, you can try to set it to `<version>2.8.11</version>` and try if your tests work. If not, then you need to figure out a "middle version" that works both for the applications in `core-module` and your tests.

Comment: Using `dependencyManagement` solved it. Thanks. Which way makes more sense? Having the `dependencyManagement` specified in the `spark-module` or in the parent POM? I believe, having in Parent POM would apply the version rule across all the modules in the project. Is that it?

Comment: While this helps, I'm just curious if the shade plugin is supposed to include the transitive dependencies from dependencies classified as `test-jar`?